# How to assign partitions of multi topics evenly when consuming multi topics in an application that runs in a cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Saying there is an application that runs in a cluster of 100 nodes. And the application consumes 20 topics, each topics have 30 partitions.

Ideally, each application instance should take 6 partitions, from same or differnt topics. But the worse case can be only 30 nodes actually working with partition assigne. And the rest nodes have no partition assigned.

Is there some way to make it close to the ideal status, that each application instance takes 6 partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the author of the question has answered the value of `partition.assignment.strategy` that he should use to get the even distribution of partition when consuming from multiple topics. I want to **emphasize the meaning of this config** and the **thumb rule** that we can keep in mind while setting this configuration.

`partition.assignment.strategy` simply decides the **order in which the partition will be distributed** amongst the consumer instances in a given consumer group.

Possible Options for this config are **Range, RoundRobin, StickyAssignor, and YourOwnCustomPartitioner**.

**Thumb rule:**

> The take-away lesson is to subscribe to multiple topics, better to use
> `RoundRobinAssignor` if the number of partitions for each topic is not
> even. But If partitions of each topic are even or just one topic. You
> could use either `RoundRobinAssignor` or `RangeAssignor` .

I quote this documentation for the above thumb rule [Partition Assignment strategy](https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab)

Another useful read is [understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3#:%7E:text=The%20basic%20idea%20behind%20Failover,to%20the%20next%20available%20consumer.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very practical.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a dummy question... Kafka have native solution for this. Config to use RoundRobinAssignor or StickyAssignor and consume multi topics in the same consumer. Assignor will handle the rest.